# KnockoutJS, updating ViewModel after ajax call

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I am using Knockout and the Knockout Mapping plugin.

- My MVC3 Action returns a View and not JSON directly as such I convert my Model into JSON.
- This is a data entry form and due to the nature of the system validation is all done in the Service Layer, with warnings returned in a Response object within the ViewModel.
- The initial bindings and updates work correctly its the "post-update" behavior that is causing me a problem.

**My problem is after calling the AJAX POST and and receiving my JSON response knockout is not updating all of my bindings... as if the observable/mappings have dropped off**

If I include an additional ko.applyBindings(viewModel); in the **success** things do work... however issues then arise with multiple bindings and am certain this is not the correct solution.

This is the HTML/Template/Bindings

```
<!-- Start Form -->
<form action="@Url.Action("Edit")" data-bind="submit: save">
<div id="editListing" data-bind="template: 'editListingTemplate'"></div>
<div id="saveListing" class="end-actions">
    <button type="submit">Save Listings</button>
</div>
</form>
<!-- End Form -->

<!-- Templates -->
<script type="text/html" id="editListingTemplate">
        <div class="warning message error" data-bind="visible: Response.HasWarning">
            <span>Correct the Following to Save</span>
            <ul>
                {{each(i, warning) Response.BusinessWarnings}}
                    <li data-bind="text: Message"></li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </div>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Key Information</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                <label>Project Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input data-bind="value: Project_Name" class="title" />
            </div>            
        </fieldset>        
</script>
<!-- End templates -->
```

And this is the Knockout/Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        @{ var jsonData = new HtmlString(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model)); }

        var initialData = @jsonData;
        var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData);


        viewModel.save = function () 
        {
            this.Response = null;
            var data = ko.toJSON(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Edit")',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                ko.mapping.updateFromJS(viewModel, result);
            }
        });
    }

    $(function() {                        
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);            
    });
</script>
```

And this is the response JSON returned from the successful request including validation messages.

```
{
    "Id": 440,
    "Project_Name": "", 
    "Response": {
        "HasWarning": true,
        "BusinessWarnings": [
            {
                "ExceptionType": 2,
                "Message": "Project is invalid."
            }, {
                "ExceptionType": 1,
                "Message": "Project_Name may not be null"
            }
        ]
    }   
}
```

**UPDATE**

[Fiddler Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/galenp/etRAJ/12/) Is a trimmed live example of what I am experiencing. I have the Project_Name updating with the returned JSON but the viewModel.Response object and properties are not being updated through their data bindings. Specifically Response.HasWarning().

I've changed back to ko.mapping.updateFromJS because in my controller I am specifically returning Json(viewModel).

Cleaned up my initial code/question to match the demo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess Response is reserved, when I change "Response" to "resp", everything went fine. See http://jsfiddle.net/BBzVm/

Comment: +Correct, Indeed this was the problem, now to refactor "Response" out of my viewModel into "Messages" or some such.

Answer (score 4):

Should't you use ko.mapping.updateFromJSON on your success event? Chapter **Working with JSON strings** on Knockout Mapping site says:

> If your Ajax call returns a JSON string (and does not deserialize it into a JavaScript object), then you can use the functions ko.mapping.fromJSON and ko.mapping.updateFromJSON to create and update your view model instead.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion previously and yielded the same result, you are correct however with your reference and I'll update my original question to use updateFromJSON.

Comment: my bad it was correct the first time using updateFromJS because i'm returning specfically Json(viewModel) in my controller. Please review the live demo link above.